# tab navigationcontroller, start in first view

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

my app is a Tab based application, in some of the tabs there are navigation controller.

[image]

If I navigated in the view, and when I'm in the second view (in the navigation) and change the tab, when I click again the tab, it starts on the second view as I finished.

So, what I want, is when changing the tab,the

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

effect. So, I will always starts on the first view.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

I add some code to my project following Bart Whiteley's answer, my MainTab.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTab : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate>

@end
```

MainTab.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSLog(@"this class is loaded");
   self.tabBarController.delegate = (id)self;
   [self setDelegate:self];
 }


 -(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
  NSLog(@"changing tab");
   if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
     [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
 }
```

SOLVED! I edit my post with the code

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of editing your question with the solution, add another answer that details it so it's more easy to find - and to keep questions separate from answers. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a delegate for the UITabBarController, and implement this delegate method:

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
     [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```